# Ошибка в коде clojure

Tags: clojure

```
(defn mapset [func ele]
  (loop [elements ele
         result []]
    (if (empty? elements)
      (set result)
      (let [[first-value & another] elements]
        (into result (func first-value))
        (recur another result)))))

(def v [1 2 3 4 5])
(mapset + v)
```

Ошибка при попытке запустить:

```
Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
```

Answer (score 0):

## Прочитайте [документацию к `into`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into).

Второй аргумент может быть **коллекцией** или **трансдьюсером**, но никак **не числом**.

Поскольку добавить вы хотите не коллекцию элементов, а только один, то вам `into` не нужен вовсе. На самом деле вам нужна [функция `conj`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj).

У вас там есть ещё одна логическая ошибка, связанная с иммутабельностью векторов. И из-за неё ваша функция `mapset` сейчас эквивалентна `(constantly #{})`. В чём именно заключается ошибка, предлагаю найти самостоятельно.